# CSS: Curved inverted clipping

Tags: css, curve, clipping

I'm trying to clip an image like the curve here:

[image]

I'm breaking my head over this, very much appreciated if someone could help me on the way. I'm pretty sure this can be done with css but if not, I'll probably end up using an svg image

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @davidxc this is an image...

Comment: @joostdelange Yes, and this page is not about doing your job, it is about helping you, when you get stuck while doing your job. Try something and com back with something you actually tried

Comment: This might help you. https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 3):

For reference: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Try to use ellipse clip-path.

```
clip-path: ellipse (radiusX radiusY at x y);
```

radiusX has to be your imageWidth*2
radiusY can be what ever you want
Afterwards set the x and y values to the bottom right corner of your image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: I downvoted because your answer was a link-only answer (Which is not allow on this site). I have now **retracted** my DV because you improved the answer and added relevant details